# What is the exact architecture/components of MinWin?

Tags: windows, windows-7, kernel

I've always wanted a minimal windows NT build . Sounds like one's already there : [MinWin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinWin). Can anyone tell me the exact design or architecture of MinWin and is it used in Windows 7 ? Windows Server 2008 already has a minimal Core build available for deployment  . Why not Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 R2 also has the same core build available for it.

Windows 7 is a client OS and it's highly unlikely that anyone would ever want to use a "core system" version of it.  For instance the core server SKU doesn't have the ability to use any video cards beyond the basic VGA driver or have a shell - the only UI is cmd.exe.  There's no .Net framework, no multimedia, etc.   As I understand it from what I've seen on the web, Minwin has even *less* functionality than core server does - from what I've seen, it doesn't even support graphics.

Comment: I'm not sure if Windows Server 2008 R2 also has the same core build. Technical Fellow Mark Russinovich(sysinternals) is the authority here. Charles Torres writes this : "Most people confuse MinWin with Windows Server 2008's ServerCore technology - the confusion stems from the incorrect assumption that ServerCore is a byproduct of the MinWin work"

Comment: I got the answer to my second question as to why not one for Windows 7..."Windows 7 is a client OS and it's highly unlikely that anyone would ever want to use a "core system" version of it.  ".... having something like Windows CE where you can build your OS would be interesting...atleast for some users..

Comment: I never said that ServerCore was MinWin.  You did.  I was just pointing out that there's a ServerCore version of Windows Server 2008 R2.

And Microsoft has something like Windows CE where you can build your own OS.  It's called Windows Embedded (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Embedded).  But it's not MinWin.

Comment: I said this :"minimal Core build available for deployment " , not that "ServerCore was MinWin".  I'm hardly an expert on this, just an avid learner. It was only after I downvoted that I realized who wrote that..  You've worked on more versions of Windows than I've used and its my privilege to hear from you on this Larry !! I was looking for something similar to David Solomon's article :http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/Xplore/login.jsp?url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fstamp%2Fstamp.jsp%3Ftp%3D%26arnumber%3D722284%26isnumber%3D15590&authDecision=-203 . There nothing on MSDN as well!!

Comment: Are there any differences in the Windows 7 scheduler and  Windows Embedded scheduler ? I last used Windows CE 5.0 (and XP Embedded) and it appears that since then MS has changed the embedded product lineup.

Comment: WinCE is not Windows Embedded.  But I don't know the details of the differences between the two, for that you'd have to ask someone like Mark Russinovich or David Soloman.